# How to understand the mean and variance of Hypergeometric distribution intuitively

Tags: probability

> Hypergeometric distribution: We have $N$ balls with $n$ red balls and $N-n$ blue balls. Now we draw k balls $(0\leq k\leq n),$ then the number of red balls among $k$ balls follows the Hypergeometric distribution.

If we denote $X_i,$ the i-th draing, $X_i =1$ if we draw red ball, else $X_i = 0.$ By induction, we can proof that $P(X_i = 1) = \dfrac{n}{N}.$ Therefore
$$E = E\left[\sum X_i\right] = k\dfrac{n}{N}.$$

My question is that

1. is there any intuitive way to understand $P(X_i = 1) = \dfrac{n}{N}$ without induction (something like binomial distribution).
2. How to compute $E[X_iX_j],\ i\neq j$ for the variance?

Let's forget the formula of `combinations number`!

Comment: Intuitively $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_1 = 1)=\frac n N $ by symmetry/exchangeability

Comment: Similarly $E[X_iX_j],\ i\neq j$ is the same as $E[X_1X_2] = P(X_1=1,X_2=1)= \frac{n(n-1)}{N(N-1)}$

Comment: @Henry could you give more detail on how to understand `symmetry/exchangeability?` If we regard as drawing one by one, they are definitely not equivalent.

Comment: For example each draw is as likely to be red as any other draw

Comment: @Henry I understand, it is sampling and random ordering, therefore every position has the equivalent distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Symmetry* suggests that $p:=E[X_i]=P[X_i=1]$ doesn't depend on $i$, and clearly $P[X_1=1] = n/N$.  (If I draw the balls from the urn, obtaining $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_k$, and then randomly reorder the results as $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_k$ before revealing them to you, the joint distribution is unchanged.)

Likewise, by the same symmetry, if $i\not=j$ then $c:=E[X_iX_j] =P[X_i=X_j=1]$ is the same for all distinct $i,j$. Therefore $c=P[X_1=X_2=1] ={n\over N}\cdot{n-1\over N-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Each $X_i$ is identically (not independently) Bernoulli with success probability $n/N$: the fraction of all balls that are red.
2. $X_iX_j,i\neq j$ is also Bernoulli with success probability $P(X_i=1,X_j=1)=P(X_i=1)P(X_j=1|X_i=1)=\frac{n}{N}\frac{n-1}{N-1}$ (due to drawing without replacement).

Comment: I still cannot be convinced by $X_i$ is  identical without calculation. For example, $X_2 = \dfrac{n}{N} * \dfrac{n-1}{N-1} + \dfrac{N-n}{N} * \dfrac{n}{N-1} = \dfrac{n}{N}.$